# Beginner question about Ports and server listening

Tags: node.js, server

I've just completed a couple of Node.js tutorials and would like a bit of clarification about server port listening and communication between computers in general.

I've created a couple of basic Node.js servers, and what I've learned in that you have to tell your server to listen on a certain port. My questions are as follows:

1. Say my computer (PC1) is listening on port 3000, does that mean when a client (say PC2) is trying to connect to my server through the internet, the client must be sending their request via port 3000 on their side for my server to receive and respond to the request?
2. Following on from Q1 - And if PC2 (client) is trying to connect to PC1 (server) and the client's port is different to what the server is listening for, does that mean nothing happens?
3. This is a very "beginnerish" question. Say I've got a basic Node.js server up and running, and a client makes a request. Before the client information even reaches the server application running in Node.js, a connection between the client and server through the internet must first be established through their IP addresses, right? Then after that, the server application will respond if the port it's listening on is the same port that the client sent the request?

I realise these are basic questions, but I'd really like to firmly grasp these concepts before moving forward with my backend adventure.

Feel free to direct me to any resources you think would help me understand these concepts better.

Many thanks!

Comment: Requests are sent over the IP address and port combination. You can have N different applications running in your system which would like to expose in the network. You do so by assigning a unique port to the network. If  client sends a request on port 3000, but your system has no application running on port 3000, the request will not resolve and will eventually time out.

Comment: Default port for Http is 80, for https the port is 443. You can use reverse proxy services like Nginx, Apache etc to route your traffic from one port to another, in this case the client sends the request on port 8080 of your Nginx server, then your Nginx server will forward the request to the application running on port 3000 and then sends the response back to the client

Comment: Okay thanks! But how does our server application know what port to listen on? So if I have a web server, it should listen on port 80? And any other requests from clients with a port than 80 won't resolve?

Comment: When you start your server application, you specify the port to listen to. In NodeJS wit Express you write `app.listen(3000)` where `3000` is the port. Your web application is free to listen to any available port on your server.

Comment: Okay great! So if I did that, only clients connecting via port 3000 would be recognized by the server?

Comment: yes, exactly. This is how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your firewall is off, and you are behind a router that forwards the port 3000 to you, then yes, your 3000 is open and you can connect freely from your publicIP:3000.

What we do normally, we listen on localhost:3000, but we firewall 3000. Then we have a frontend reverse proxy (nginx, HAProxy), that reverses port 80(http)/443(https) to 3000.

Reverse proxy allows listening to different domains as well, so you can have a app on 3000, a app on 3001 for different apps, and redirect different domain to it.

If you cannot access from PUBLIC IP because you are behind a local area network, then you can install something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) which allows you to tunnel your connection from the internet.